# using Tool part how to set multiple value to List property of web part?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, toolpart

In Tool part I create check Box List property.I want to set this property web part but its not work.for single value its work but I want to set multiple values.

```
 public override void ApplyChanges()
    {
        CustomizableFilter customizableFilterWebPart = (CustomizableFilter)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart;

        int count = 0;
        foreach (ListItem item in CategoryCheckBoxList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                selectedCategory.Add(item.Value);
            }
            count++;
        }
        customizableFilterWebPart.categoryValues = selectedCategory;

    }
```

Get the values using below code

```
  var selectedItems = ((CustomizableFilter)this.ParentToolPane.SelectedWebPart).categoryValues;
```

Comment: How is `categoryValues` defined in your code, is it a string?

Comment: categoryValues is property that are define in webpart with type as List.

Comment: I think you can make it string and use comma separated values for saving selected items. That way it will be easier to handle and should work